# PHP Mysql real time message?

Tags: php, mysql

I programmed a chat client with PHP and MySQL. The pattern is the following right now:

**sendMessage.php**

Insert message into the correct chatRoom

**loadMessages.php**

The already downloaded messages are cached
So it downloads only the new messages since the last downloaded message ID..

(For example if chatMsg1 has been already downloaded but there is chatMsg2 then the loadMessages.php gives back only the chatMsg2)

— — — — — — — —

Everything works fine, but I’m a bit frustrated.. I’m using that for an iOS application which calls the loadMessages.php every second..

Even if there’s no new messages, the php file does 2 queries:

- query check for valid session
- select chatRooms and check if chatRoom’s last messageId is never than the cached one (in this case no)

But still, 2 queries every second..

**Is there a way to prevent that?**

For example if user 1 is active and user 2 sends him a message then

- send directly to user 1 the message (instead pulling data every second)
- save message in the database

..?

**Is it possible to do this with only PHP or with some kind of framework?
... Or am I forced to use Google’s firebase(?) and stuffs like that**

Comment: NodeJs, Sockets.  Basically when using a traditional sever it's not suited for this (pulling).  Things like NodeJs, or a socket server are more better for real time pushes.  FYI, I write code that can do 180k queries a minute or 3k per second (uses Sphinx though), my point is the DB can handle it.  Ive done over hundreds of query per second, maybe 16k per minute.

Comment: Of course if performance become an issue you could use something like Cassandra or another NoSQL platform (I would thing Cassandra would be a good fit).  In other words, unless you want to take the time to take a radical approach, all you can do is make sure you index, optimize queries and worry about performance when it becomes an issue.  Of course this is largely Opinion based.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thank you very much, that Sphinx is interesting. Yeah I’ve read a few articles about noSQL platforms, but I’m not in the position right now to use those:c

Comment: Sphinx is not a good choice for this, sphinx is a good choice for high read low write data.  Meaning data that doesn't change often that has to be read a lot.  It's about 10-20x faster then MySql, but you have to reindex it to update (you can do live indexing but ... thats another story for another day)

Comment: Honestly you don't get a big benefit from NoSql, unless you use a cluster of servers.  And they are more targeted at a specific need where as MySql is more general purpose.  None of that would solve your issue, as a traditional client->server setup is not well suited for this.

Answer (score 1):

For theese type of applications you need to be able to serve content via websockets. In other words you need to create a php websocket server like http://socketo.me/ where the content is delivered real-time

Answer (score 0):

use push notification in sendMessage.php also save data to db.
IOS application calls loadMessages.php whenever push arrive so if there is no new messages for next one day there will be no call and when application gets push notification it will calls loadMessages.php.
plus you can include Sender name profile pic or message in push.
you can use firebase or apple push server.